# mongo find data not using someone index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a unique index, but now some data does not have this index, resulting in duplicate data, I want to find out this part of the data, I want to query data that does not have this index.
Like this:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
MongoDB server version: 4.0.12

# there is no not_hint func
db.col.find().not_hint("md5_1_domain_1_ip_1_uri_1")

# hint not allowed to use $ne
db.col.find()._addSpecial("$hint", {"$ne": {"md5" : 1, "domain" : 1, "ip" : 1, "uri" : 1}})
```

The unique index

```
{
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "md5" : "hashed"
                },
                "name" : "md5_hashed",
                "ns" : "mdm.col"
},
{
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "md5" : 1,
                        "domain" : 1,
                        "ip" : 1,
                        "uri" : 1
                },
                "name" : "md5_1_domain_1_ip_1_uri_1",
                "background" : true,
                "ns" : "mdm.col"
}
```

The data, I have modified some sensitive information and I am sure they are the same. And the data cannot be queried by a unique index. Only use _id or the other index to query.

```
mongos>  db.col.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb2df3b32b0f42dced04ea7")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb2df3b32b0f42dced04ea7"), "domain" : null, "ip" : 1, "md5" : BinData(5,"anQTYWNGHKoj4xx+KTjNxQ=="), "uri" : "x * 1025", "count" : 6, "fseen" : ISODate("2019-08-03T13:56:38Z"), "lseen" : ISODate("2019-08-03T13:56:38Z"), "sha1" : null, "sha256" : null, "src" : [ "xx2", "xx3" ] }
mongos>  db.col.find({'_id': ObjectId('5fb2df3d32b0f42dced0721d')})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb2df3d32b0f42dced0721d"), "domain" : null, "ip" : 1, "md5" : BinData(5,"anQTYWNGHKoj4xx+KTjNxQ=="), "uri" : "x * 1025", "count" : 6, "fseen" : ISODate("2019-08-03T13:56:38Z"), "lseen" : ISODate("2019-08-03T13:56:38Z"), "sha1" : null, "sha256" : null, "src" : [ "xx2", "xx3" ] }
mongos>  db.col.find({"md5": BinData(5,"anQTYWNGHKoj4xx+KTjNxQ=="), "uri": "x * 1025", "ip": 1}
mongos>  # it is None
```

And this info:

```
mongos> db.col.find().count()
5549020886
mongos> db.col.find().hint("md5_1_domain_1_ip_1_uri_1").count()
5521037206
```

The uri length is over 1024 and the data is not indexed. I want to find that 27983680 terms data and repair it.

Thanks

Comment: No idea what you mean by "I have a unique index, but now some data does not have this index". Either you have an index or not. When it is a unique index then you cannot have duplicate data.

Comment: The fact is that I have duplicate unique index data, or I have some data that skips the unique index. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: It's not possible, in this case you don't have a unique index. Please show the index specification and some sample data.

Comment: May be you can use a [partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/).

Comment: Added sample data. @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange how it could be. Anyway, you can find duplicate data with this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            md5: "$md5",
            domain: "$domain",
            ip: "$ip",
            uri: "$uri"
         }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      ids: { $push: "$_id" }
   },
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

The result has field `ids` with array of `_id` from duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this method, because there is too much data, it will throw UnknowError the next day. And I think it still works through a unique index, but it's useless for that part of the data.

Comment: I found the reason. The URI length is over 1024 and the data is not indexed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The `uri` length is over 1024 and the data is not indexed.The DBA colse `failIndexKeyTooLong`. But I still can't find this part of the data.